# Is it worth to partition a MySQL table on a key, if this key is already an index?

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing, partitioning

I have a big MySQL table (around 50 GB, tens of millions of records), with one index key (a foreign key) that has around 2000 possible different values, and another index key (a VARCHAR(2)) that has 3 possible values.

Can I expect a significant performance increase if I partition the table based on either (or both) indices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't partition on a column that is not an index (or part of it), so yeah... it is worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of de-normalising the table when there is three possible values if you have performance problems?

Comment: Do you mean I should split the table into three with the same columns (except the splitted column)?
I would like to avoid that as it makes it more complicated to maintain and it somehow defeats the abstraction layer...